# Delete Script in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

I need help in making delete script. I have data like this :

[Redemption vs CGT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABo2y.jpg)

Currently I have data showing the count of Redemption i.e RNCount and count of CGT i.e CGTCount. Logically One redemption must have one CGT and 2 Redemption must have 2 CGT.

Currently there is data error and I want to delete all those wrong entries.
For RnCount 1 there must be 1 CgtCount , for 2 RN there must be 2 CGT and so on..
How can I do this?

currently I've done something like this but I am not sure what should I do further?

```
 DECLARE @tsd_acccode
 DECLARE @tsd_realizeddate
 DECLARE @prd_productcode
 DECLARE @tsd_trxsubtype

SET @tsd_acccode = (what should be here?)
SET @tsd_realizeddate = (what should be here?)
SET @prd_productcode = '5f9bf8f6-ace5-430c-bfc1-4550f09b9b8d' 
SET @tsd_trxsubtype = 'RNCT'

DECLARE dupCGT
CURSOR LOCAL STATIC
FOR

SELECT 
     A.tsd_acccode
    ,A.tsd_realizeddate
    ,A.prd_productcode
    ,A.tsd_trxtype

FROM
(
SELECT Count(*) trxcount, tsd_acccode, tsd_realizeddate, prd_productcode, tsd_trxtype

from is_trx_trx_processed 

where tsd_trxsubtype = @tsd_trxtype
and @tsd_acccode =  @tsd_acccode
and @tsd_realizeddate = @tsd_realizeddate
and @prd_productcode = @prd_productcode


group by tsd_acccode, tsd_realizeddate,prd_productcode, tsd_trxtype

) A

WHERE A.trxcount > 1

order by A.trxcount, A.tsd_acccode, A.tsd_realizeddate


OPEN dupCGT

FETCH NEXT FROM dupCGT
INTO  @tsd_acccode
      ,@tsd_realizeddate
      ,@prd_productcode
      ,@tsd_trxtype

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM IS_TRX_TRX_PROCESSED 

   where tsd_trxsubtype = @tsd_trxtype
   and @tsd_acccode =  @tsd_acccode
   and @tsd_realizeddate = @tsd_realizeddate
   and @prd_productcode = @prd_productcode

    FETCH NEXT FROM dupCGT
    INTO @Block_id
END

CLOSE dupCGT
DEALLOCATE dupCGT
```

Comment: can you please post sample data with schema..?

Comment: How many duplicated rows are you dealing with total?  Btw, your cursor looks like it will delete all records with duplicates (not just the duplicates, but all of them)

Comment: @tgolisch its around 4321 rows out of 159388

Comment: @ShakeerMirza sure..